# EF5 Enums and Lookup Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-5

I am attempting to implement Enums with my lookup tables in EF5.  I am using model first.  I have a main entity called "Appraisal" that has a column "Appraisal_Type_ID".  This is an INT in the database.  I also have an entity called "Appraisal_Type", which also contains "Appraisal_Type_ID" as well as a description.  There is an association between the two entities and I switched the Int to an enum on both the main Appraisal table and the lookup table.  Here is what the two entities look like in the generated code:

```
public partial class Appraisal
{
    public Appraisal()
    {
        this.Goals = new HashSet<Goal>();
        this.NewGoals = new HashSet<NewGoal>();
        this.CompetencyResults = new HashSet<CompetencyResult>();
        this.Attachments = new HashSet<Attachment>();
        this.Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
        this.NewCompetency_Results = new HashSet<NewCompetency_Results>();
        this.AppraisalActivityLogEntries = new HashSet<AppraisalActivityLogEntry>();
    }

    public int Appraisal_ID { get; set; }
    public string Penn_ID { get; set; }
    public string Review_Year { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor_Penn_ID { get; set; }
    public AppraisalType Appraisal_Type_ID { get; set; }
    public int Appraisal_Status_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Last_Update_Date { get; set; }
    public string Last_Update_User { get; set; }
    public string Future_Development { get; set; }
    public string Rating_Comments { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Supervisor_Sign_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Employee_Sign_Date { get; set; }
    public string Employee_Comments { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Next_ReviewDate { get; set; }
    public string Home_Dept_Org { get; set; }
    public string Home_School_Ctr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ContentType_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Rating_Code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Final_Step_Reached { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor_Name { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor_Job_Class { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor_Job_Title { get; set; }
    public string Current_Editor { get; set; }
    public string Current_Editor_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewGoal> NewGoals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompetencyResult> CompetencyResults { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual AppraisalUser AppraisalUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewCompetency_Results> NewCompetency_Results { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppraisalActivityLogEntry> AppraisalActivityLogEntries { get; set; }
    public virtual Appraisal_Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Rating Rating { get; set; }
    public virtual Appraisal_Type AppraisalType { get; set; }
}

public partial class Appraisal_Type
{
    public AppraisalType Appraisal_Type_ID { get; set; }
    public string Appraisal_Type_Desc { get; set; }
}

public enum AppraisalType : int
{
    Appraisal = 2,
    SelfAppraisal = 1
}
```

I can easily grab the Appraisal from the database and it works fine with the enum, and I can easily grab the Appraisal_Type data from the database and it works fine with the enum.

However, the goal is to use an .Include to get the Appraisal_Type with the Appraisal.  This throws an error.

```
public Appraisal GetAppraisal(int appraisalID)
    {
        using (AppraisalEntities context = new AppraisalEntities(AppraisalEntitiesConnectionString))
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

            Appraisal data = context.Appraisals
            .Include("Goals")
            .Include("NewGoals")
            .Include("CompetencyResults")
            .Include("CompetencyResults.Competency")
            .Include("NewCompetency_Results")
            .Include("NewCompetency_Results.NewCompetency")
            .Include("Attachments")
            .Include("Rating")
            .Include("Notes")
            .Include("AppraisalUser")
            .Include("Status")
            .Include("AppraisalType")
            .Include("ContentType")
            .First(c => c.Appraisal_ID == appraisalID);

            return data;
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

***The type of the key field 'Appraisal_Type_ID' is expected to be 'PennHR.HRManager.BusinessServices.Appraisals.AppraisalType', but the value provided is actually of type 'System.Int32'.***

It looks like EF is trying to validate the key as I see this in the call stack:

```
    System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateTypeOfKeyValue(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EdmMember keyMember, Object keyValue, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName) +11452250
System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateEntityKey(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EntitySet entitySet, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName) +158
System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.CheckKeyMatchesEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySetForType, Boolean forAttach) +84
System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded) +269
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +262
lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +2651
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +10995785
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext() +277
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement() +31
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext() +78
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +247
System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +490
PennHR.HRManager.BusinessServices.Appraisals.AppraisalManager.GetAppraisal(String pennID, String reviewYear, AppraisalType type) in d:\Users\Blickley\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRManager\Trunk\HRManagerSolution\HRManager.BusinessServices\Appraisals\AppraisalManager.cs:359
PennHR.HRManager.Portal.Appraisals.AppraisalsDefault.btnViewSelfAppraisal_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Users\Blickley\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRManager\Trunk\HRManagerSolution\HRManager.Portal\Appraisals\AppraisalsDefault.aspx.cs:228
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

If I remove the .Include on the AppraisalType, everything is fine.  This code also works fine, so it seems to be the include that is causing issues:

```
    public Appraisal_Type GetAppraisalTypes()
    {
        AppraisalEntities context = new AppraisalEntities(AppraisalEntitiesConnectionString);
        Appraisal_Type data = context.Appraisal_Types
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Appraisal_Type_ID == AppraisalType.Appraisal);
        return data;
    }
```

I can't seem to find much on the error, can anyone think of a way to work around this?  I would love to be able to use enums with my lookup tables together.  If I remove the enum and switch it back to Int, everything works fine again.

Comment: Try removing  : int from the end of public enum AppraisalType

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make a difference.  I think the EF is testing the type of the value coming from the database, seeing it is an Int32, and throwing the error because it wants it to be the enum type.  What isn't clear is why this only fails on the the "Include".

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repro for this? Just two entities with just necessary proprties and the mapping between these? At the moment there seems to be too much irrelevant information...

Comment: Similar (no answer yet): http://stackoverflow.com/q/12220956/861716